# setprecision evaluation order

Tags: c++, iostream

```
streamsize prec = cout.precision();  
std::cout << setprecision(3) << 10.000001 << setprecision(prec);
```

In c++, "although the implementation is required to execute the `<<` operator from left to right, it is not required to evaluate the operands in any specific order."

Then, how can we assure that `setprecision(3)` is evaluated before `setprecision(prec)`?

Thanks!

Comment: `setprecision(3)` does not set the precision to 3. It **returns** an object that will set the precision to 3 when inserted into the stream.

Comment: `setprecision` can't have any effect on the stream on its own, since it doesn't have any idea about which stream you want to manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

You already did so. Sure, the actual `setprecision(prec)` might be evaluated first. But it doesn't *do* anything until it is "shifted" into the stream. Running:

```
setprecision(prec);
```

doesn't do anything (useful) on its own, it's only when the `operator<<` of a stream is invoked with it as an argument that anything happens, and as you note, the invocation of the serial `<<` has guaranteed left-to-right evaluation order. So it's already doing what you want; `setprecision(prec)` may be constructed early, but it won't affect the stream in any way until `setprecision(3)` has modified the stream and `10.000001` has been written.

Answer (score 0):

Before C++17,

[evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) of `setprecision(prec)` can indeed be evaluated before `setprecision(3)`

From C++17,

> 19) In a shift operator expression `E1<<E2` and `E1>>E2`, every value computation and side-effect of `E1` is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of `E2`

But in your case, anyway, [std::setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) only creates an (unspecified) object, which once used with `stream << unspecified_object` behaves as if `str.precision(n)` was executed.

So evaluation order between `setprecision(prec)` and `setprecision(3)` doesn't matter.